# Stuck here while using Keras (2.3.1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

## DataSet

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

## normalizing

```
x_train = keras.utils.normalize(x_train,axis=1)
x_test = keras.utils.normalize(x_test,axis=1)
```

## model

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(x_train))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128,activation= keras.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128,activation= keras.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation= keras.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy']
)
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=3)
```

## ERROR:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2.3.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aditya/Desktop/Desktop/dataScience/Practice/OpenCV/FaceDetect/Hackathon/classMnist.py", line 28, in <module>
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(x_train))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 495, in __init__
    self.data_format = K.normalize_data_format(data_format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 311, in normalize_data_format
    data_format = value.lower()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

The problem is that the Keras can't flatten the x_train. So Do you know why throw this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(x_train))
```

The Keras create a network that can't load data.

```
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=3)
```

There are data loaded.

So you should edit the first code:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
```

And your codes have other error:

```
# wrong
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128,activation= keras.nn.relu))
# right
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128,activation= keras.backend.relu))
```